# Looking for a sci-fi book from the 1960s-70s about moving objects to change the course of history

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

The plot was that people from the future did extensive research and then made one small change to the past (like moving an object from one side of a room to another) that resulted in a major shift in the future story arc.

Any ideas would be most welcome!­

Answer (score 51):

In Asimov's [The End of Eternity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_End_of_Eternity) (1955) the timeline-changing Eternals pride themselves on making the Minimum Necessary Change to bring about their desired results.  In one example in the book this consists of moving a container from one shelf in a cupboard to another.

Comment: A great book and title!

Comment: @Organic Marble: Thank you!! Yes, it is The End of Eternity. I've already started reading it and am loving it all over again.

Comment: Glad that was it! Please accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark on the left!

Answer (score 4):

Not a full book but a really great short story that has spawned many movies and spin offs.A Sound of Thunder by Ray Bradbury. This short story was published in 1953. I know outside your time frame but a classic staple of all Sci-Fi collections.

Comment: I don't think it can be this, there was no "extensive research" in A Sound of Thunder; it was about a hamfisted accident by one clumsy poltroon.

Comment: I only added that comment because I had a sudden desire to use the word "poltroon".

Comment: @Whelkaholism It's a good word.

Comment: @Rachel_eh: I've added it to my reading list. Thanks.